# Error when using SnowPark and fuzzywuzzy in Anaconda

Tags: package, anaconda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I'm working on a project where I need to use SnowPark in Anaconda and incorporate the functionality of `fuzzywuzzy` from the following package: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake/.

To provide context, I'm loading a fictitious table from Snowflake using the following code:

```py
df = snowflake_session.sql(query_sql)
```

The table has the following format:

```
----------------------
|  "col1" |  "col2"  |
----------------------
| 1111111 | 1111112  |
| 2222222 | 2222222  |
| 3333333 | 1333243  |
----------------------
```

> Note: The `df` is of type: <snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame

The first thing I do is install the package in my Anaconda virtual environment:

```py
!conda install --name snowflake_env -c https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake fuzzywuzzy
```

Now, I import the `fuzzywuzzy` library and use it in my function, which I define as follows:

```py
import fuzzywuzzy as fuzz

@udf(name="fuzzy", is_permanent=False, replace=True, packages=['fuzzywuzzy'])
def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int:
    return fuzz.ratio(x, y)
```

I apply the function to the columns of my dataframe:

```py
df.select("col1", "col2", fuzzy("col2", "col2")).show()
```

However, when executing this code, I get the following error:

```
SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01b05970-0303-0e9b-0000-77590c4bc49a: 100357 (P0000): Python Interpreter Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 37, in compute
  File "_udf_code.py", line 26, in wrapper
  File "C:\Users\es_oriol\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1234\660708773.py", line 5, in fuzzy
NameError: name 'fuzzywuzzy' is not defined
 in function FUZZY with handler compute
```

This leads me to believe that there's an issue with the import of `fuzzywuzzy` within my `fuzzy` function, correct? Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this?

I appreciate any help in advance!

Thank you!
Oriol

I have tried reinstalling the package, registering it to snowflake, changing anaconda virtual environment, etc....

Comment: I believe your import is wrong. It should be `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz` since if I just try your import I see: `>>> import fuzzywuzzy as fuzz
>>> fuzz.ratio('123', '1234')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'fuzzywuzzy' has no attribute 'ratio'
>>>`

Comment: Thank you very much @Sergiu, you are right. Anyway, the same error is still coming up.
\\
```python
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

@udf(name="fuzzy", is_permanent=False, replace=True, packages=['fuzzywuzzy'])
def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int:
    return fuzz.ratio(x, y)
```

and the erro is:
```python
SnowparkSQLException: (1304): blah blah blah 
File  "C:\Users\es_oriol\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1234\660708773.py", line 5, in fuzzy"
NameError: name 'fuzzywuzzy' is not defined
 in function FUZZY with handler compute
```

Thank you in any case :)

Comment: This is very strange indeed. I believe as a workaround you can import the library after function definition, like `def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int: from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz return fuzz.ratio(x, y)`. This should work, but I believe it's not what the official docs are saying. If it works let me know, I'll take it up internally on Snowflake.

Comment: Hello again Sergiu and thank you very much for responding so quickly.  I would like to comment that the same error persists when I write this:

```python
@udf(name="fuzzy", is_permanent=False, replace=True, packages=['fuzzywuzzy'])
def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int:
    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    return fuzz.ratio(x, y)```

thank you :)

Comment: Give me a day or two and I will test it from my side and see if it's a bug. Seems to be working when I quickly test it using Snowflake UI.

Comment: Perfect Sergiu! thank you very much! I will be waiting for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps I followed worked for me.

I created a virtual env using conda like:

```
conda create --name snowflake_env --override-channels -c https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/snowflake python=3.9 snowflake-snowpark-python fuzzywuzzy
```

The list of packages installed is:

```
$ pip list
Package                    Version
-------------------------- ------------
asn1crypto                 1.5.1
Brotli                     1.0.9
certifi                    2023.7.22
cffi                       1.15.1
charset-normalizer         2.0.4
cloudpickle                2.0.0
cryptography               41.0.3
filelock                   3.9.0
fuzzywuzzy                 0.18.0
idna                       3.4
mkl-fft                    1.3.8
mkl-random                 1.2.4
mkl-service                2.4.0
numpy                      1.26.0
oscrypto                   1.3.0
packaging                  23.1
pip                        23.3
platformdirs               3.8.1
pyarrow                    10.0.1
pycparser                  2.21
pycryptodomex              3.15.0
PyJWT                      2.4.0
pyOpenSSL                  23.2.0
PySocks                    1.7.1
python-Levenshtein         0.12.2
pytz                       2023.3.post1
PyYAML                     6.0.1
requests                   2.31.0
setuptools                 68.0.0
snowflake-connector-python 3.2.0
snowflake-snowpark-python  1.9.0
sortedcontainers           2.4.0
tomlkit                    0.11.1
typing_extensions          4.7.1
urllib3                    1.26.18
wheel                      0.41.2
```

I created a small python script to use the same udf as you:

```
$ cat stackoverflow.py 
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from snowflake.snowpark import Table
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


connection_parameters = {
        "account": "XXXX",
        "user": "XXXX",
        "password": "XXXX",
        "role": "XXXX",
        "warehouse": "XXXX",
        "database": "XXXX",
        "schema": "public"
    }
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()

df = session.sql("SELECT * FROM test_fuzz")
#df = session.table('test_fuzz')

@udf(name="fuzzy", is_permanent=False, replace=True, packages=['fuzzywuzzy'])
def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int:
    return fuzz.ratio(x, y)

df.select("col1", "col2", fuzzy("col2", "col2")).show()

session.close()
```

I run it:

```
$ python stackoverflow.py 
---------------------------------------------------
|"COL1"   |"COL2"   |"FUZZY(""COL2"", ""COL2"")"  |
---------------------------------------------------
|1111111  |1111112  |100                          |
|2222222  |2222222  |100                          |
|3333333  |1333243  |100                          |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now, when I check in Query History via Snowflake UI I can see a temporary function is created and I can see this part:

```
# The following comment contains the source code generated by snowpark-python for explanatory purposes.
# import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz as fuzz
# @udf(name="fuzzy", is_permanent=False, replace=True, packages=['fuzzywuzzy'])
# def fuzzy(x: int, y:int) -> int:
#     return fuzz.ratio(x, y)
#
# func = fuzzy
```

In your case the above code is missing the import part:

```
# import fuzzywuzzy.fuzz as fuzz
```

I can only think of something related to your local environment. As a side note, I've tested this on both Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10, exact same steps and on both it worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi Sergiu,

Thanks for your detailed Snowflake setup guide. Planning to try it this week. Will check my environment if issues arise. Appreciate your help! Your instructions are being very clear and are incredibly helpful.

Best,
Oriol

Comment: Hello Sergiu,

Finally I have been able to restart this topic and I would like to thank you for the effort, because finally we can say that Yes, it is working!

Eternally grateful,
Regards,
Oriol